# Get smallest N values from numpy array ignoring inf and nan

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy

I need a good, quick method for finding the 10 smallest real values from a numpy array that could have arbitrarily many `nan` and/or `inf` values.

I need to identify the indices of these smallest real values, not the values themselves.

I have found the `argmin` and `nanargmin` functions from numpy.  They aren't really getting the job done because I also want to specify more than 1 value, like I want the smallest 100 values, for example.  Also they both return `-inf` values as being the smallest value when it is present in the array.

`heapq.nsmallest` kind of works, but it also returns `nan` and `-inf` values as smallest values.  Also it doesn't give me the indices that I am looking for.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: iterate over/copy the array, convert all nans and -inf into inf run your function to get smallest N values, convert them back/revert to the old copy? silly hacky, but hmm...

Comment: thanks for the help, that is what I will have to do if I can't get a simpler answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only values that should be throwing this out are the negative infinite ones. So try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(20)
a[4] = -np.inf
k = 10
a[np.isneginf(a)] = inf
result = a[np.argsort(a)[:k]]
```

Comment: `2*np.max` doesn't work if all elements are negative, better to just use `inf` I think.

Comment: The solution as it stands can be dangerous. It should be noted here that you *are changing the array* to make a measurement. It may be physically significant that `-inf` is **not** `inf`.

Comment: You can avoid modifying the original array if you want. Just sort unconditionally, then limit your results to finite values: `i = np.argsort(a); result = i[np.isfinite(a[i])][:10]`

Comment: @Blckknght yes that's a better solution. If you post that I'll remove my answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you could just take the first `n` finite values from your sorted array, instead of trying to modify the original array, which could be dangerous.

```
n = 10
b = np.sort(a)
smalls = b[np.isfinite(b)][n:]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find the index of `inf` and `Nan` like this:

```
a=np.array([[12,12,111],[np.inf,np.inf,1,2,3],[np.nan,7,8]])
```

the you can loop through `a` and check it with:

```
for item in a:    
    idxInf=(np.isnan(a[item])).nonzero()
    idxNan=(np.isnan(a[item])).nonzero()
```

i.e:

```
In [17]: (np.isnan(a[2]))
Out[17]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [18]: (np.isnan(a[2])).nonzero()
Out[18]: (array([0]),)
```